# How to filter the useFetch function in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

I want to filter my data to only fetch it when my the date is before the date of today

```
const { data: persons } = await useFetch(urlPersons)
const date = new Date();
const fullYear = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-0"+date.getDate();
```

```
<h1>Testing api</h1>
<div v-for="data in persons" >

    <div>Name :{{data.name}}</div>
    <div>Startdate : {{data.startdate}}</div>
    <div>date today : {{fullYear}}</div>
    <div v-if="data.funfacts.funFact1">{{ data.funfacts.funFact1 }}</div>

  </div>
```

It works when i put a filter in my template but i wonder if i can filter it in javascript so that it doesnt fetch all the date

```
<div v-for="data in persons" >
<div v-if="data.startdate>fullYear">
  <div>Name :{{data.name}}</div>
  <div>Startdate : {{data.startdate}}</div>
  <div>date today : {{fullYear}}</div>
  <div v-if="data.funfacts.funFact1">{{ data.funfacts.funFact1 }}</div>

</div>
```

this works